# How to get the following limit into indeterminate form?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am struggling to get the following limit into its indeterminate form so that i can apply the l'Hopitals rule:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}(\sin x)^x$$

A solution would be greatly appreciated, been struggling on this one for hours now

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far or ideas you might have on it?

Comment: I let y=(sinx)^x, then i applied lny=xln(sinx),now this lead to lim  ln(sinx)/1/x being indeterminate i then applied l'hopitals rule to ln(sinx)/1/x and was left with cotx/1/x but i can not seem to get a result, because if I keep applying l'hopitals rule on the function it stays undefined. Would be greatly appreciated if you could point out if i went wrong or steps to solve this :3

Comment: $0^0$ is already an indeterminate form: you mean to get it into the specific form $0/0$.

Comment: Did you try simplifying? e.g. $\cot(x) = \cos(x)/\sin(x)$?

Comment: In general, if you already know something (e.g. the trick of taking the log to convert exponentiation into multiplication), you should put it into the question: ideally, you want to be able to ask a question about the *specific* thing you're having problems with, rather than the less precise "I was unable to solve this exercise".

Answer (score 2):

$(\sin x)^x \to x \log \sin x = \frac{\log \sin x}{\frac{1}{x}}$

Comment: but how can i just add a log like that and move the x to the bottom? I previously used xln(sinx)

Comment: Please see the edit. I'm sorry for the typo. You need to consider $Lf(x) = x \log \sin x$ obtained by logging the original function.

Comment: @Git Gud The limit defnition?

Comment: @JoshBoiskin Disregard my comment, I thought you didn't know that $f^g=\exp \circ (g(\log \circ f))$. But I see you do.

Answer (score 1):

As a similar and useful hint, one can use the definition of [Infinitesimal Functions](http://portal.tpu.ru/SHARED/k/KONVAL/Sites/English_sites/calculus/2_InfinitesimalClass_f.htm) here. In fact, while $x\to 0$ we have $\sin x\sim x$ . Now apply the method you know. I mean put $y=x^x$ and then...

Comment: Awsome think i have solved it, managed to get undefined as i am left with lim x->0   1/tanx  thus making it undefined :)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the equation equal to y then applying the natural log to each side. I prefer working with ln rather than log because it's easier to derive.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (\sin x)^x & = \exp\left(\log \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (\sin x)^x\right)\right)  \\
& = \exp\left(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \log \left( (\sin x)^x\right)\right)\\
&= \exp\left(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x \log  (\sin x)\right)\\
&= \exp\left(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\log  (\sin x)}{\frac1x}\right)\\
\text{or}&= \exp\left(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{x}{\frac{1}{\log  (\sin x)}}\right)\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Write:
$$e^{x\ln \sin x}=e^{x\ln \frac{\sin x}{x}+x\ln x}$$
If $x\rightarrow 0$ we have
$$\ln \frac{\sin x}{x}\rightarrow 0$$
and
$$e^{x\ln \frac{\sin x}{x}+x\ln x}\sim e^{x\ln x}$$
but
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln x}{1/x}=\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{-\ln t}{t}=0$$
Then, result is $1$.